# Twitter not working

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

i used MGTwitterEngine and its not working the application crashes after successful login attempt please help me

Comment: the twitter is not working on iPhone app basically i used iOs 4.1 SDK

Comment: You forgot to post your code. It's awfully hard to see it from where we're all sitting.

Comment: Post some code and the log from the console and we might be able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my code @Yorxxx

I just use the MGTwitterEngine:

following are the website i take the tutorial for help but its not working :(

```
    #pragma mark twitter

- (void) twitterAction{

    if(_engine) return;

    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey = @"pDFl6Og4Uwq2qEoJaOiuw";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"p3gxIDewgK3nxueJIRKPoSoFEpp8RtIryglvOrwSQA";

    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

    if (controller)
        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    else {
        tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self updateStream:nil];
    }

}

-(IBAction)updateStream:(id)sender {
    [_engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1 count:100];
}

-(IBAction)tweet:(id)sender {

    [_engine sendUpdate:@"Testing Testing Testing ... Please Wait"];
    [self updateStream:nil];


}

#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate

- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *) data forUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSUserDefaults  *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject: data forKey: @"authData"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username {

    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"authData"];
}

#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterController Delegate

- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSLog(@"Authenticated with user %@", username);

    tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self updateStream:nil];
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerFailed: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller {

    NSLog(@"Authentication Failure");
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerCanceled: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller {

    NSLog(@"Authentication Canceled");
}
```